# Connection refused by NGSI-Proxy

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

Using the last version of ngsi-proxy to make Orion related wirecloud components work I get the following error when configuring my Orion Source component:

2fb0de97f49a.js:1737 GET http://localhost:3000/eventsource/12caae10-30eb-11e7-95ac-d72bca8f4488 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My configuration of the component is the following:

[image: Orion Source Configuraiton]

And I am running both Orion Context Broker (v1.7) and Wirecloud (v1.0) running locally. Version of the Orion Source operator is the latest I have found (3.0.7). No security is configured.

Could anyone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the ngsi-proxy didn't answer properly. I solved by using the public ngsi-proxy: https://ngsiproxy.lab.fiware.org (as it comes by default).